# How to establish dtype in pandas when you do not know the columns name?

Tags: python, pandas

In an application I am developing, I import a csv file and I have been establishing dtype doing this:

```
def read_vcf(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
        dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
               'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
        sep='\t'
    ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})
```

Sample_name will change as this application will open many files. However, the file must have the same number of columns. I was wondering and looking at it but unlucky if I could establish this by location. If the number of columns is lower than expected I will also arise a warning or Error message. But this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Will the columns be in the same order, even if they don't have the same names?

Comment: yeah it has to be or it should be

Comment: You can get the column names from the csv file by only reading the first line (or whichever line has the column names in it). Something like `pd.read_csv(filename_or_string, header=None, nrows=1)` (you may need to modify options to suit your needs). Once you get the column names, you can (somehow) dynamically assign the dtypes and then re-read the entire csv file.